# Transformation of a XOR Function to another XOR Function

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Since my function of XOR and the implementation in my book of XOR are both implementations of XOR, there should be a way to transform mine to the other one right?

My implementation:
$$
(x_0 \lor x_1) \land (\overline x_0 \lor \overline x_1)
$$

The implementation in the book:
$$
(x_0 \land \overline x_1) \lor (\overline x_0 \land x_1)
$$

I tried to do it by myself, but it did not really worked out, so if anyone know how to transform it or know if it is even possible help would be appreciated

Comment: Just use the distributive property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the two are equivalent:

Try distribution:

$$(x_0 \lor x_1) \land (\overline x_0 \lor \overline x_1)) = \big(\underbrace{(x_0 \land \bar x_0)}_{\text F} \lor (x_0 \land \bar x_1)\lor (x_1 \land \bar x_0) \lor \underbrace{(x_1 \land \bar x_1)}_{\text F} \\= (x_0\land \bar x_1)  \lor (x_1\land \bar x_0)$$

Note that two terms in the distribution are false: a variable cannot be both true and false,  so that leaves you with the result.

Comment: that was very helpful, thanks

Comment: Glad to help, David!

Answer (score -1):

If you interchange $\land$ for $\times$ and $\lor$ for $+$, they become:

$$(x_0 + x_1) \times (\overline x_0 + \overline x_1)$$

$$(x_0 \times \overline x_1) + (\overline x_0 \times x_1)$$

As $x\bar{x}=0$, going forward is easy. Going backwards just takes a little imagination!

Comment: Did you mean to write $x\times\bar{x}=0$?